# when i remove the values from array after adding in to the dictionary.The array values are removed from the dictionary in iOS?

Tags: ios, nsarray, nsdictionary

Iam adding the array in to the dictionary then remove the all objects from array.When i print the dictionary it is also shows empty.Means the array data present in dictionary also removing.

```
if ([[[testMenuGroupAry objectAtIndex:0]objectAtIndex:group] isEqualToString:[filteredAry objectAtIndex:objCount]])
    {
        NSLog(@"object count is %d",objCount);
        [groupAry addObject:[array1 objectAtIndex:group]];
    }

    [tempDict setValue:groupAry forKey:[filteredAry objectAtIndex:objCount]];
    [groupAry removeAllObjects];

    NSLog(@"before Dictionary temp Dict : %@",tempDict);
```

The tempdict also shows the empty.Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this line of code:

```
[groupAry addObject:[array1 objectAtIndex:group]];
```

to

```
[groupAry addObject:[[array1 objectAtIndex:group] mutableCopy]];
```

this will help the objects to be retained and your array will not become nil.

Answer (score 1):

Because you removed all its elements. Adding objects to collections doesn't **copy** them, it just **retains** the instance.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because your dictionary stores only a reference to your array. It does not copy the whole array. What you can do is copy the array first and then store it in the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

if you want the tempdict not to be empty. you should do this:
 [tempDict setValue:[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:groupAry] forKey:[filteredAry objectAtIndex:objCount]];
It makes a copy of groupAry.